# Why is there no @NotFunctionalInterface?

Tags: java, lambda, interface, annotations

Often when designing an API I'm confronted with a warning stating that an interface (that just so happens to contain one abstract method) "may be annotated with @FunctionalInterface".

It often happens with custom listeners (somewhat like `ActionListener`), but also with things like this:

```
public interface CommunicatorEnumerator {
    List<Communicator> enumerateCommunicators();
}
```

One thing all these interfaces have in common, is that it isn't excluded that someone will add more abstract methods in the future. So ideally I'd like to prevent such interfaces from being used in lambdas.

Having `@SuppressWarnings("InterfaceMayBeAnnotatedFunctional")` doesn't prevent lambda use. I'd like to mark them as "not functional interface".

So why isn't there a construct (it doesn't have to be an annotation) that prevents lambda use of interfaces?

Comment: If you add a (non-default) method to an interface, you're breaking your API anyway (anybody who implements the interface is required to add the method).

Comment: You can extend an FunctionalInterface with a sub-interface with more methods. This is just a warning in your IDE, you can turn it off.

Comment: @Mark I don't see a single use case for this.

If you want to disallow the use of a class in client code, simply use visibility modifiers (you can keep an interface package-private, or class-private if you wrap it in a outer type).

If you want to disallow the use of a class *inside the API*, well, you really can't, because the developer has full access to the code itself and can do any change he wants. You could maybe just document the intended usage, but that's about it.

Comment: What problem will preventing lambda use solve?

Comment: I guess I was a bit hypocritical because, if a developer who adds methods to an interface can fix it's usages, he can also fix lambda usage (if there's any).

Answer (score 0):

This is just a warning by the IDE, you should be able to turn it off or disable it selectively.

Using @FunctionalInterface doesn't prevent extension.

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface ISuper {
    void methodOne();
}
public interface ISub extends ISuper {
    void methodTwo();
}

public enum Sub implements ISub{
    INSTANCE {
        @Override
        public void methodTwo() {
            System.out.println("Wave Two");
        }

        @Override
        public void methodOne() {
            System.out.println("Wave One");
        }
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ISuper sup = () -> System.out.println("Hi");
    sup.methodOne();

    Sub.INSTANCE.methodOne();
    Sub.INSTANCE.methodTwo();

    ISub sub = new ISub() {
        @Override
        public void methodTwo() {
            System.out.println("Bye");
        }

        @Override
        public void methodOne() {

        }
    };
    sub.methodTwo();
    }
}
```

prints

```
Hi
Wave One
Wave Two
Bye
```

I would disable the warning where it doesn't apply and not worry about extending a `@FunctionalInterface`

Comment: Being able to extend an interface that's `@FunctionalInterface` is another design quirk, but it's a whole other can of worms that I don't plan to open. Besides it isn't what I asked about.